# Positioning a view partially outside the screen in Android

Tags: android-layout

How do I place a view partially outside the screen in Android?The view that needs to slide in is placed inside a RelativeLayout as of now and here is the entire layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webViewLink"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The second webview is the one which needs to be partially outside the screen.

Comment: did you try `android:layout_marginRight="-30dp"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `android:layout_marginRight="-30dp"` as @user1490103 suggested. Or you could use `android:translationX`. The translation would make more sense if you are planning on animating this View. Remember to [set](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#attr_android:clipChildren) `android:clipChilren="false"` on the RelativeLayout.